# How can I set default color in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides, text-formatting

Every time I enter text into a new text box, or draw a new line, or a new shape, etc. The color is black (on a dark background) and I need to manually change it to white. This is getting tedious. Is there a way to set the default color?

I tried editing the theme (**Slide > Edit Master**) but all the text there was already white, and I couldn't find anything to change.

Comment: This happens even on the default themes, which makes me pessimistic that this is a changeable value.

Comment: This question on Google Support forum: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3505539?hl=en you can upvote it to bring more attention to the issue

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is (as yet) impossible, the quickest workaround I've found for a new textbox with pre-set color and font is to copy an existing text box, either from your current slide or another.

The only tricky part about this is selecting the text box itself without generating a cursor within in the text (you don't want to copy TEXT, but the whole box).  In many cases you can just click inside the existing box, but not on the existing text, but this gets tricky with overlapping text boxes.